# Select when value is not present in either of 2 columns

Tags: mysql

I have two fields, `email` and `addlEmail`.  I need a select that only selects the record if a given email address is not in either field.

Attempt at using NOT IN with two columns (returns: `Cardinality violation: 1241 Operand should contain 2 column(s):`)

```
SELECT WebUsername, 
  WebPassword, 
  Active, 
  Email, 
  AddlEmail, 
  ShowYear 
FROM Exhibitors e 
WHERE e.Active = '-1' 
AND e.ShowYear = 2013 
AND (e.Email, e.AddlEmail) NOT IN ('test@test.com', 'test2@test.com')"
```

I have tried AND and OR, they do not work for obvious reasons.

For the sake of trying to be thorough:

```
$emails = "'email@email.com', 'email2@email.com'";
// example table data for 2 fields in question
Row | Email              |   AddlEmail
1   | email@email.com    |   email3@email.com
2   | email4@email.com   |   email2@email.com
3   | email5@email.com   |   null
4   | email6@email.com   |   email7@email.com
```

The query should only return rows 3 and 4.

Thanks for taking a look, and please let me know if you need further clarification.

Chris

EDIT:
Sample table in response to answer posted:

```
CREATE TABLE `doubleSelect` (
  `Email` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AddlEmail` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `doubleSelect` (`Email`, `AddlEmail`) VALUES
  ('email@email.com', 'email2@email.com'),
  ('email2@email.com', 'email3@email.com'),
  ('email4@email.com', 'email5@email.com'),
  ('email6@email.com', 'email@email.com'),
  (NULL, 'email@email.com'),
  ('email2@email.com', NULL);
```

Sample Query (does not return the last row, and it should):

```
SELECT *
  FROM `doubleSelect`
  WHERE Email NOT
  IN (
    'email@email.com'
  )
  AND AddlEmail NOT
  IN (
    'email@email.com'
  )
```

Comment: Try: AND e.Email NOT IN ('test@test.com', 'test2@test.com') AND e.AddlEmail NOT IN ('test@test.com', 'test2@test.com')"

Comment: @Ascension, I replied below but see your comment now. Using this will return all 4 results above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
select * 
from Exhibitors 
where (email is null or email not in('email@email.com', 'email2@email.com'))  
and   (addlEmail is null or addlEmail not in ('email@email.com', 'email2@email.com'))
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Using the sample table above, this does return the correct results.  I'll try it in the actual code soon, it may be complicated by the additional `AND`'s

Comment: Here is the modified code (this is Drupal 7 btw): `$exhibitors = db_query("SELECT WebUsername, WebPassword, Active, Email, AddlEmail, ShowYear FROM {Exhibitors} e WHERE 
  (
    e.Email IS NULL
    OR e.Email NOT
      IN (
        :notIn
      )
   )
   AND 
  (
     e.AddlEmail IS NULL
     OR e.AddlEmail NOT
       IN (
         :notInHere
       )
   )
   AND e.ShowYear = :showYear
   AND e.Active = '-1'", 
  array(':notIn' => $notIn, ':notInHere' => $notIn, ':showYear' => $showYear)
  );`

Comment: This does not work, it returns all results with ShowYear = 2013 and Active = '-1'. $notIn = 'test3@test.com','ctaylor@removed.com','alice@removed.com.cn'.  Those results are coming back.

Comment: My issue was Drupal stripping single quotes out of my variable replacement.  Your solution accounts for NULL values, therefore it is more correct for my use case.  Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

simply

```
AND e.Email NOT IN ('test@test.com', 'test2@test.com') 
AND e.AddlEmail NOT IN ('test@test.com', 'test2@test.com')
```

including NULL values:

```
SELECT *
FROM `doubleSelect`
WHERE (Email IS NULL or Email NOT IN ('email@email.com'))
      AND (AddlEmail IS NULL or AddlEmail NOT IN ('email@email.com'))
```

Comment: This doesn't account for when the email is in `Email` but not in `AddlEmail`, or vice versa.  This would return all 4 rows in the example data.

Comment: I believe I've confirmed that this does not solve it, and have edited the question to reflect that.

Comment: See my response to the answer I accepted.  Your answer is generally correct, and I was messing something else up; however, the accepted answer accounts for NULL values which is more useful for me.  My question was not thorough enough for you to know that, so I wish I could mark yours as accepted also.  Thanks for responding!